# Add method to STL class at compile time

Tags: groovy

I'm wondering is there some possibility to add method to `Object.class`, but not during runtime (so `.metaClass` property is not an answer to this), but compile time like for instance `Local AST Transformations` do (unfortunatelly can't place annotation on `Object.class`). I believe this is possible since there is `Class` called `GroovyDefaultMethods` which does that (add some methods to every class from Java STL). Can someone tell me how it's done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groovy has [Extensions](http://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_extension_modules), which are applied in runtime without the need to use metaClass. They are also statically compilable.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I'm searching for, though didn't know the name for it :)